# How to load XML into datasets on load in a dynamic PDF form (LiveCycle)?

Tags: pdf, livecycle, xfa, dynamicpdf

I need to pre-fill a dynamic PDF's fields so my users can edit it and submit back.

I am using Adobe ColdFusion CFPDFFORM tag that can load XML data into a PDF and make a new populated PDF. Unfortunately it also clears **<xfa:datasets>** tag, it completely empties it out! So all dropdownlists binded to datasets do not work. This is the code for binding one of them:

```
<bindItems ref="xfa.datasets.LOVFile.LOV.PreferenceLanguageList.PreferenceLanguage[*]" labelRef="$" valueRef="lic"/>
```

Since I have no control on how CFPDFFORM tag works, I came up with a workaround. Using LiveCycle Designer for codding, I store whatever data there is in **<xfa:datasets>**  into a variable and load it to datasets at form::initialize.

This seems to load datasets fine, just like how they were before cfpdform messed them up. After loadXML() call , I can read the datasets and get identical results as in the original PDF with its datasets tag full of XML data.

```
form1::initialize - (JavaScript, client)
//xfa.host.messageBox("loading xml to datasets");
xfa.datasets.nodes.namedItem("LOVFile").loadXML(LOVFile_var.value,0,1);
Page1.Header.debug.rawValue = xfa.datasets.LOVFile.LOV.PreferenceLanguageList.resolveNode("PreferenceLanguage[2]").value;
```

The problem is down down lists still don't work, they have no item to show. Somehow their binding call to datasets does not refresh?

Is there anything else I should do after loadXML() ? LiveCycle reference for *bindItems* says "*The links between the list items and the referenced data are active. Any change to the data causes an immediate update to the list items.*"

Any help or point to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

using azathoth's answer I can add item to a dropdownlist using data from the newly loaded datasets (after loadXml() call).

```
var oEyeColors = xfa.datasets.LOVFile.LOV.resolveNode("EyeColorList");
var numberOfNodes = oEyeColors.nodes.length;       

var thisValue = "";

for (var i=0; i < numberOfNodes ; i++){
    thisValue  = oEyeColors.nodes.item(i).value;
    if(thisValue == null){
        thisValue = "";
    }
    xfa.resolveNode("Page1.eyeColorDropDownList").addItem(thisValue.toString());

}
```

This works but is not the solution I am looking for. There must be a JavaScript way to set bindItems of a dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

I do what you specify with this code:

```
xfa.datasets.loadXML(LOVFile_var.rawValue, false, false); 
xfa.datasets.saveXML();                                 
var yourXML = xfa.datasets.resolveNode("yourXMLRootNodeName");
var numberOfNodes = yourXML.nodes.length;       

for (var i=0; i < numberOfNodes ; i++)
    yourDropDown.addItem(yourXML.nodes.item(i).nodes.item(1).value); // this can change according to what you retrieve in your xml
```

Tell me if it worked for you

Comment: Thx this helps for sure. But I want to keep it as the last resort since there are lots of dropdownlists in the form and some are changed as the user fills out the form. I had to make a few changes to make it work. I updated the post.

Comment: I am still looking for a way to bind datasets to dropdownlists after datasets are updated.

Comment: you can use a script object so that it will populate any dropdown with a certain dataset, with something like:
`function populateDropDown(dropdown, datasetName)`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is what you're looking for?

Pre-populating dropdown lists in dynamic PDF forms from a back-end data source using LiveCycle ES2.5

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/prepopulating-dropdown-lists.html